# Is it possible to skip a level in a Hierarchy using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

The Hierarchy is in XML format and I am  using XSLT to transform the data.

For eg : If the Hierarchy has 4 levels and I want to skip a level in between (say level 3) :

```
Level 1
    Level 2 
        Level 3 - Skip this level
            Level 4 
                Level 5
```

What element should I use to achieve the same?

Attaching the sample XML file which I have as an input for reference

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
    <Board>
        <Name>President</Name>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        <ParentId></ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>President</Name>
            <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>VP</Name>
        <Id>EFGHI</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>VP</Name>
            <Description>Below the President</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
        <Id>JKLMN</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the VP</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Supervisors</Name>
        <Id>OPQRS</Id>
        <ParentId>JKLMN</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Supervisors</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL4</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Employees</Name>
        <Id>TUVWX</Id>
        <ParentId>OPQRS</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL5</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Update : I am adding the expected output and the xslt transformation i currently use.

The expected output is below :

The transformation I am currently using is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Hierarchy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Hierarchy/Board">

                <xsl:if test="General/Template='LEVEL1'">
                    <xsl:variable name="Presidentchild" select="Id"/>
                    <Board>
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </Name>
                        <Template>PRESIDENT</Template>
                        <Description>
                            <xsl:value-of select = "General/Description"/>
                        </Description>
                    </Board>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Board">
                <xsl:if test="ParentId = $Presidentchild">
                    <xsl:if test="General/Template='LEVEL2'">
                        <Board>
                            <xsl:variable name="VPchild" select="Id"/>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                            </Name>
                            <Template>VICE_PRESIDENT</Template>
                            <Description>
                                <xsl:value-of select = "General/Description"/>
                            </Description>
                        </Board>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Hierarchy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

........so on till the last element.

The expected ouput is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
  <Board>
    <Name>President</Name>
    <Template>PRESIDENT</Template>
    <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
    <Board>
    <Name>VP</Name>
    <Template>VICE_PRESIDENT</Template>
    <Description>Below the President</Description>
    </Board>
   </Board>
</Hierachy>
```

... so on till the last element.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing a sample input, the expected output and your current attempt. -- Hint: this is rather trivial if you start with the *identity transform* template and add an overriding template for the level/s you want to "skip" - a template that does nothing except apply templates to the children of the context element.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : I have updated the question as mentioned by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to your question I said this is rather trivial. That is because I thought your input XML had a hierarchical structure. As it turns out, the hierarchy needs to be derived by tracing the cross-references from each `Board` to its parent.

Still, because each `Board` also includes a (misnamed) `Template` element that indicates its level in the hierarchy, it is easy to "skip" certain levels, such as `LEVEL3` in the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="Board" use="ParentId" />

<xsl:template match="/Hierarchy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Board[General/Template='LEVEL1']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="General/*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', Id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board[General/Template='LEVEL3']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', Id)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
  <Board>
    <Name>President</Name>
    <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
    <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
    <Board>
      <Name>VP</Name>
      <Description>Below the President</Description>
      <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
      <Board>
        <Name>Supervisors</Name>
        <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
        <Template>LEVEL4</Template>
        <Board>
          <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
          <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
          <Template>LEVEL5</Template>
        </Board>
      </Board>
    </Board>
  </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Comment: just an additional question in this. Now that we skip an element , the parent id of the child of skipped element becomes irrelavant and the element is not related to the hierarchy. For eg: The skipped element here is "Department head", and the "ParentId" of Supervisor is the Id of DepHead. But after skipping, the ParentId of supervisor still remains the same, thus removing the relationship in the hierarchy. Is it possible to change the ParentId of supervisor to change to the Id of VicePresident? Sorry if my question is confusing. @michael.hor257k

Comment: This is rather confusing because the result here has no `ParentId`.

Comment: Ok. Now what if I want to add the Ids.. what if i add something like this to include Parentid and Id :

<xsl:template match="Board">
    <xsl:copy>
    <Id>
                <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
            </Id>
            <ParentId>
                <xsl:value-of select="ParentId"/>
            </ParentId>
<xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

Now in this case it selects the value as is... but as i mentioned above, i want to change the Parentid to the Id of the element above the skipped element.

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you post a new question and explain exactly what you need.

Comment: Maybe I will try to frame my question one last time, if it still isnt clear, then I will post a new question.