# Skip an element and all its child elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to skip a particular element and all its child elements.for eg:

```
1. Audi
    1.1 Engine
            1.1.1 Piston
            1.1.2 Crankshaft
    1.2 Transmission
            1.2.1 Gears
            1.2.2 Shift

2. Ferrari
    2.1 Engine
            2.1.1 Piston
            2.1.2 Crankshaft
    2.2 Transmission
            2.2.1 Gears
            2.2.2 Shift
    

3. Ford
    3.1 Engine
            3.1.1 Piston
            3.1.2 Crankshaft
    3.2 Transmission
            3.2.1 Gears
```

Here is the XML doc

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
    <Board>
        <Name>Audi</Name>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        <ParentId></ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Audi</Name>
            <Description>Car brand</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Engine</Name>
        <Id>EFGHI</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Engine</Name>
            <Description>Part of Car</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Piston</Name>
        <Id>JKLMN</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Part of Engine</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Crankshaft</Name>
        <Id>OPQRS</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Part of Engine</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Transmission</Name>
        <Id>TUVWX</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Transmission</Name>
            <Description>Part of Car</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Gear</Name>
        <Id>CSDKL</Id>
        <ParentId>TUVWX</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Gear</Name>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Shift</Name>
        <Id>SDKLFH</Id>
        <ParentId>TUVWX</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Shift</Name>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Lets say I want to skip only the "Engine" from audi and all its child elements, how do i do it?

I usually create xslt mentioning some of the attributes from the XML file, like Id etc. But it is a long process since I have to type the Id's of all the child elements of Engine as well. Gets way more complicated when I have 100k elements.

The expected output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
    <Board>
        <Name>Audi</Name>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        <ParentId></ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Audi</Name>
            <Description>Car brand</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    
    <Board>
        <Name>Transmission</Name>
        <Id>TUVWX</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Transmission</Name>
            <Description>Part of Car</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Gear</Name>
        <Id>CSDKL</Id>
        <ParentId>TUVWX</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Gear</Name>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Shift</Name>
        <Id>SDKLFH</Id>
        <ParentId>TUVWX</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Shift</Name>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Please note that I have mentioned only "Audi" part of the hierarchy, for Ferrari and Ford, I would require all the data as is in the output.

Comment: Do you know in advance the `Id` of the Engine from Audi (`EFGHI` in your example? Also, please edit your question and add the expected result.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Yes the ID will be available. Also updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858493/3016153), this is complicated because there is no direct connection between an element and its ancestor. There needs to be an interim step to find all descendants of the part you want to remove - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="remove-id">EFGHI</xsl:param>

<xsl:key name="children" match="Board" use="ParentId" />

<xsl:template match="/Hierarchy">
    <!-- construct a list of Ids to remove -->
    <xsl:variable name="blacklist">
        <Id>
            <xsl:value-of select="$remove-id"/>
        </Id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', $remove-id)" mode="blacklist"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Board[not(Id = exsl:node-set($blacklist)/Id)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board" mode="blacklist">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Id"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', Id)" mode="blacklist"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```