# Relink the parentID of the child of skipped element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to change the ParentId of the child of the skipped element using xslt. My input file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
    <Board>
        <Name>President</Name>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        <ParentId></ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>President</Name>
            <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>VP</Name>
        <Id>EFGHI</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>VP</Name>
            <Description>Below the President</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
        <Id>JKLMN</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the VP</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Supervisors</Name>
        <Id>OPQRS</Id>
        <ParentId>JKLMN</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Supervisors</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL4</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Employees</Name>
        <Id>TUVWX</Id>
        <ParentId>OPQRS</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Employees</Name>
            <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL5</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Expected Output file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
  <Board>
    <Name>President</Name>
    <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
    <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
      <Id>ABCDE</Id>
      <ParentId></ParentId>
    <Board>
      <Name>VP</Name>
      <Description>Below the President</Description>
      <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
       <Id>EFGHI</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
      <Board>
        <Name>Supervisors</Name>
        <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
        <Template>LEVEL4</Template>
        <Id>OPQRS</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <Board>
          <Name>Employees</Name>
          <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
          <Template>LEVEL5</Template>
           <Id>TUVWX</Id>
        <ParentId>OPQRS</ParentId>
        </Board>
      </Board>
    </Board>
  </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Now with the help of another question i raised, I am able to find a way to skip elements. Question link below :
[Is it possible to skip a level in a Hierarchy using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763772/is-it-possible-to-skip-a-level-in-a-hierarchy-using-xslt)

But If you observe in the expected output, The ParentId of Supervisors is changed to the Id of VP, thus skipping the element "Depeartment Heads" altogether. Is this possible? Can someone give a possible solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you need the `Board` elements to continue to carry their parent's `Id`, after you have changed the structure to a proper hierarchical one.

Anyone receiving a result in the following format:

```
<Hierarchy>
    <Board>
        <Name>President</Name>
        <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
        <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        <Board>
            <Name>VP</Name>
            <Description>Below the President</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
            <Id>EFGHI</Id>
            <Board>
                <Name>Supervisors</Name>
                <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
                <Template>LEVEL4</Template>
                <Id>OPQRS</Id>
                <Board>
                    <Name>Employees</Name>
                    <Description>Reports to the Reports to Dep Heads</Description>
                    <Template>LEVEL5</Template>
                    <Id>TUVWX</Id>
                </Board>
            </Board>
        </Board>
    </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

can easily see that the parent of the `Board` named `Supervisors` is the `Board` named `VP`, and its `Id` value of `EFGHI` is readily available using the expression `parent::Id`.  Duplicating this value in a separate `ParentId` element is utterly redundant.

Still, if you want this unnecessary complication, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="Board" use="ParentId" />

<xsl:template match="/Hierarchy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Board[General/Template='LEVEL1']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board">
    <xsl:param name="parentId" select="ParentId"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="General/*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Id"/>
        <ParentId>
            <xsl:value-of select="$parentId"/>
        </ParentId>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', Id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board[General/Template='LEVEL3']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', Id)">
        <xsl:with-param name="parentId" select="ParentId"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes you won't be skipping two or more consecutive levels.

Comment: I apologise for not mentioning that I might have to skip multiple elements. What I have mentioned here is just sample data, but in reality, there are thousands of elements and I have to skip multiple levels sometimes.

Comment: You can skip multiple elements, just not a parent/child pair. If you might need to do that, you will have to "carry" the `parentId` parameter through all the skipped levels.

Comment: The solution you have provided is creating an extra layer of "Board". Something like this : `<Board> <Board>
        <Name>President</Name>
        <Description>Top level of the Hierarchy</Description>
        <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        </Board>
        <Board> `......

Here there are two boards instead of just one, in just one element

Comment: I don't think so. You can see here that it produces exactly the expected output shown in your question: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7C